# Complex join with different data types in laravel 8 query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, query-builder

I have two tables **Infos** and **nationalities** like this :

**1) Table infos:**

| id(pk) | name | nationality(varchar) accept multiple nationalities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | Camilia | 2,4 |

**1) Table nationalities :**

| id(pk) int | desig |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | German |
| 2 | Turkey |
| 3 | Algeria |
| 4 | Qatar |

I want to get in the output something like this:

| desig | count |
| --- | --- |
| German | 1 |
| Turkey | 2 |
| Algeria | 1 |
| Qatar | 1 |

So for that I tried something like this(but it did not help):

```
$total_nationalite = DB::table('infos')
                    ->select('desig', 'nationalities.id',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
                    ->join('nationalities', DB::raw('CAST(nationalities.id as varchar)'), '=', 'infos.nationality')
                    ->groupBy('desig','nationalities.id')
                    ->get();
```

please any suggestion with the **query builder** or with a **simple query in postgres.**

Comment: You could pick up that string representing the nationalities per "person", e.g. "1,2,3" , then separate it out based on the separator & then turn that into a column and finally be able to do a count of these values.
 However I think it would be better to introduce a third table that will simply have 2 columns , the 1st being the ID from infos, the 2nd being the ID from nationalities .. then your counting would be trivial. You could also add attributes to that "bridge table" (which allows you to deal with many-to-many relationships) e.g. date_nationality_acquired, naturalisation_flag, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a comma separated list of values text in `nationality` field is a bad idea. Have an array of integers or - much better - a normalized design. Anyway here is a native query solution.

```sql
select desig, count(*) count  
from
(
  select unnest(string_to_array(nationality, ','))::integer nat_id 
  from infos
) t
join nationalities n on t.nat_id = n.id
group by desig;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3pJMhDN4Dkh4mBr6uqfjVm/0)

| desig | count |
| --- | --- |
| German | 1 |
| Qatar | 1 |
| Algeria | 1 |
| Turkey | 2 |